# A practical way to project large-scale vectors (of size millions) to 2d space

Tags: projection

I have several (dozens) of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with $d$ being in millions). My goal is to project them into a 2-dimensional space. 
A couple of things that I know:

- I know that projection from high-dimensional space could be pretty tricky, since we might be losing lots of information (that are encoded in high-dimensional space but might be representable in a 2d space).
- I know that there are several tools for projection. For example, [t-SNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html#sklearn.manifold.TSNE) or random projections.

I am looking for suggestions as to what is an efficient/practical way to do this. As of know, here are the two settings I have in mind:

1. Random: project the points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ directly onto $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. Random + t-SNE: the points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ to an intermediate dimension (say, $1000$ dimensional space), followed by a projection onto a $\mathbb{R}^2$ space with t-SNE.

I don't apply t-SNE directly since I think it wouldn't scale to large-scale vectors.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how I can do a better projection?

Comment: Calculate the covariance matrix and project onto the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues. ... works for me.

Comment: I think this is an unanswerable question unless you can [edit] it to tell us what you want to achieve with this projection. What problem do you want to solve with this projection? You ask for something "better" but that's not a mathematical criterion.